# What is the best way to implement Custom Web Analytics in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-analytics, analytics, reporting

The existing SharePoint 2013 web analytics doesn't help when I want to extract reports like

1. User names and email addresses of users
2. Page-wise hits
3. Device and location of user
4. Leverage employee information from HR to get department/gender-wise top visitors

How I do implement a custom solution to get such reports?

PS: Would prefer an on premise solution, since there are security risks associated with cloud services like Google analytics.

Comment: Have you checked for Azure Analytics tool..It's quite amazing and may answer all your requirements

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to Microsoft’s Azure Application Insights, which will provide you some extraordinary reports for these kind of requirements. It is very easy to configure your SharePoint On-Premises site with Azure Application Insights, which will provide more information than you require.

Here are the steps to configure SharePoint Site in Application Insights.

**Step 1**

Go to [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/) and select Application Insight menu. Then, create new Application Insight and provide mandatory fields.

**Step 2**

After that creating Insight do the following steps:

**Application Insights => Demo Insight (Application Insight created from you) => getting started => Monitor and diagnose client side application => Copy the script from the Guidance section**.

**Step 3**

Once successfully performed the above steps, open your SharePoint Site Collection in SharePoint Designer or whatever you have to customize SharePoint page, then paste script (copied script from Guidance Section) inside header section in Seattle. Master page.

Now you will be able to get the reports from Azure Application Insight.

If you want a comprehensive set of audit and security reports, you can look up Vyapin’s [SharePoint Audit and Reporting tool](http://www.vyapin.com/products/sharepoint-management/dockit-sharepoint-manager/) for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I haven't tried the Azure analysis channel yet, thanks for that info!

A simpler channel is the standard SharePoint Usage Reports in SP Admin panel.  Sometime in the 'near future' this will be able to provide additional user activity - not defined or timelined just yet.